# Restart First Activity in BroadcastReceiver Class

Tags: android

Main Activity

```
public static void restartFirstActivity()
{
    Intent i = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                                      .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName() );

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity(i);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver class

```
import com.example.aa.MainActivity;

public class NetworkChange extends BroadcastReceiver{
    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
    ma.restartFirstActivity();
}
```

I have an error in MainActivity's static.

Comment: I have a non static method getApplicationContext() cannot be referenced from a static contex error

Comment: That error means exactly that - you can't call non-static methods from a static method. I suspect either restartFirstActivity should not be a static method, or you should not be calling getApplicationContext from that method. In your code, when you call restartFirstActivity, it does not need to be a static method. However, you should not be calling `new` on an activity class, Android creates activities for you, so I think your approach might not be the right one to take.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
import com.example.aa.MainActivity;

public class NetworkChange extends BroadcastReceiver{
    Intent a = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(a);
}
```